# Device roll compensation on augmented reality

Tags: iphone, ios, augmented-reality, device-orientation

I'm working on an app that performs geolocalization over the camera stream of the iPhone. I use the compass to figure out where to put the icons and information onto the the camera layer. If I rotate the device around yaw axis everything works fine.

However, when I roll the iPhone all the information on screen goes away. That's because when you roll the device the compass orientation also changes. However, there are apps like Layar or Wikitude that allow roll rotation without losing focus on the visual items you have onto the camera layer. That way, these apps allow smooth transition between portrait orientation to landscape orientation.

How they achieve that? How can I compensate the roll rotation of the device to keep information on screen?

By the way, the ARKit framework has the same problem as me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you are in 2D maybe it is enough to take the point you are calculating from camera field view and offset heading, calculate the distance to the center of the screen, and use that distance as a radius for a circle to do x += r*cos, y += r*sin with -roll as the angle, so the object moves in a circle against the roll. Then you just have to counter rotate the image itself with a transform (CGAffineTransformMakeRotation) to keep it vertical.